# OpenVPN restart systemd service if TLS error occured

Tags: openvpn, systemctl

I have a systemctl service which starts openvpn command with given config file.
`openvpn *filename*`
But if somebody uses same certificate to open VPN from another device - service logs TLS errors and VPN stops working. But the service doesn't stop and restart after that. It continues to work even through VPN doesn't.
How can I manage the service to restart after the error occured? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why share certificates between systems? I would start by fixing that.

Comment: @vidarlo I want to have guarantees that if this will happen - VPN will be reloaded automatically.